# Lenovo ThinkVision T2224dA shows "menu is blocked" each 10 seconds

Tags: windows-10, thinkcentre

I'm using a Lenovo ThinkVision T2224dA and each 10 seconds (*at the very center of the screen*) a blue, rectangle message appears with the text:

- Menu is blocked

and

- Menu is unlocked

I've searched how can I disable such message (*or, at least, make it less noticeable*), but, in the [user manual](https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/visuals/t2224d_60eb_usereng.pdf) doesn't mention anything that solves this problem.

I don't know about if it's something about its BIOS or another unknown configuration I'm unable to find - either by pressiong the OSD (*On-Screen Display*) or another entries in webpages or forums -.

It there a way to disable that message showing each 10 seconds in the very center of the screen?

---

The message happens while the screen is on - no matter the application running at the moment - even when I'm editing this question, coding in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, etc.

This message shows no matter the action made, that is, when I'm active (*typing on the keyboard, for example*) or inactive (*no actions are made*).

The only background process I know is running is Microsoft Teams and FortiClient 6.0.10.0297.

This is not a new screen, it was given for WFH (*working from home*).

Comment: More infomation is needed: what are you doing when this happens? what applications are running (those in background as well as those you start)? When did this first occur?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the message happens while the screen is on - no matter the application running - even when I'm editing this question for add these details, it's when I'm active (*typing on the keyboard, for example*) or inactive (*no actions are made*). the only background process I know is running is Microsoft Teams and FortiClient 6.0.10.0297. Is not a new screen, it was given for WFH - I don't know anything else, but, if you have more hints, I will edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like Lenovo software.  Does it happen while Safe Mode?

Comment: See https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Displays-Options-and-Accessories/Lenovo-e2323-Monitor-stuck-in-Menu-is-locked-menu-is-unlocked/m-p/3994377?page=1#5011182 regarding stuck OSD button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message you are seeing on the screen is probably not from Windows but the On-Screen Display of the monitor itself. The manual you linked says on page 2-4 that you can press and hold the enter button on the monitor for 10 seconds to lock the OSD and press and hold again for 10 seconds to unlock. Sounds like this button has a problem.

Comment: I've pressed and holded the OSD button and no changes - (*those messages keep showing*); it seems a problem with the OSD button as you mentioned. When I press the OSD button, I don't feel any "stuck" - those frontal buttons are kind of hard to press and after 5-10 seconds, I don't see or heard if any settings was made.

Comment: If that monitor was mine I would dismantle it, look for dirt in that button, use some contact spray on it and check for a loose solder and fix that. But as you mentioned it belongs to your employer you're probably better off just telling them.